# Drop a specific file from the Linux filesystem cache?

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, cache

I know I can [drop everything from the Linux filesystem cache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17936/setting-proc-sys-vm-drop-caches-to-clear-cache), but is there a way to drop just one specific file?  Or prevent a file from being cached?  Or tell a process not to cache any files it writes?

I have a process that reads a lot of little files and writes a big file.  I want to keep the little files in cache to avoid disk seeks, and I don't care about caching the big file.

Comment: Regarding the bounty, I am specifically interested in the title question: **dropping a specific file from the cache** (as opposed to preventing it from getting there in the first place).

Answer (score 28):

### Potential Method #1 - F_DROP_CACHES

I found a method from 2012 that discusses a proposed patch to the Linux kernel in this mail thread titled: [Re: [RFC Patch] fs: implement per-file drop caches](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/5/30/298).

*excerpt*

> Cong> This is a draft patch of implementing per-file drop caches.
>
> Interesting.  So can I do this from outside a process?  I'm a
>   SysAdmin, so my POV is from noticing, finding and fixing performance
>   problems when the system is under pressure.
>
> ```
> Cong> It introduces a new fcntl command  F_DROP_CACHES to drop  
> Cong> file caches of a specific file. The reason is that currently  
> Cong> we only have a system-wide drop caches interface, it could  
> Cong> cause system-wide performance down if we drop all page caches  
> Cong> when we actually want to drop the caches of some huge file.
> ```
>
> How can I tell how much cache is used by a file?  And what is the
>   performance impact of this when run on a busy system?  And what does
>   this patch buy us since I figure the VM should already be dropping
>   caches once the system comes under mem pressure...
>
> Cong> Below is small test case for this patch:

The thread includes both a testcase and the actual patch to several files within the Linux kernel which adds an additional function to `fs/drop_caches.c` called `drop_pagecache_file(struct file *filp)`. This function is then accessible through the frontend tool, `fnctl.c` via the command `F_DROP_CACHES`. This case calls this function:

```
file_drop_caches(filp, arg);
```

Which handles the dropping of all the caches associated with the given file. From the file `include/linux/mm.h`:

```
void file_drop_caches(struct file *filp, unsigned long which);
```

***So this can be used?***

I found no evidence that this patch ever made its way into the main Linux kernel code repository, so this option would appear to be available, only if you're willing to recompile the Linux kernel yourself.

### Potential Method #2 - Using dd

In that same thread, another user mentions a completely different methodology that makes use of `dd`.

*The following is excerpt [from that email](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/5/30/276)*

> This is useful functionality. Though isn't it already provided with
>   `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED`? This functionality was added to [GNU dd (8.11)
>   a year ago](http://git.sv.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commitdiff;h=5f31155).
>
> Here are the examples from that patch:
>
> - Advise to drop cache for whole file
>
>   ```
>    $ dd if=ifile iflag=nocache count=0
>   ```
> - Ensure drop cache for the whole file
>
>   ```
>    $ dd of=ofile oflag=nocache conv=notrunc,fdatasync count=0
>   ```
> - Drop cache for part of file
>
>   ```
>    $ dd if=ifile iflag=nocache skip=10 count=10 of=/dev/null
>   ```
> - Stream data using just the read-ahead cache
>
>   ```
>    $ dd if=ifile of=ofile iflag=nocache oflag=nocache
>   ```

***Testing it out***

I wasn't 100% positive how to test this out but I came up with the following approach.

1. make a 100MB file

   ```
   $ dd if=/dev/urandom of=sample.txt bs=100M count=1
   ```
2. trace file accesses using `fatrace`

   ```
   $ sudo fatrace | grep sample.txt
   ```
3. run `top` so we can monitor memory usage, note amount free.

   ```
   $ top
   ```
4. open file, note amount of free memory now. Note the `fatrace` of the file `sample.txt`.

   ```
   $ cat sample.txt > /dev/null
   ```
5. drop the file from memory, note amount of free memory now. Note the output of `fatrace`.

   ```
   $ sudo dd of=/home/saml/tst/162600/sample.txt \
       oflag=nocache conv=notrunc,fdatasync count=0
   ```

#### Example

*In terminal #1:*

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=sample.txt bs=100M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 7.37996 s, 14.2 MB/s

$ ls -l sample.txt 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 104857600 Oct 17 22:54 sample.txt
```

*In terminal #2:*

```
$ top
...
KiB Mem:   7968336 total,  6900956 used,  1067380 free,   267080 buffers
...
```

*In terminal #3:*

```
$ sudo fatrace | grep sample.txt
```

*Now open the file, `sample.txt`, and note the amount of RAM. In terminal #1.*

```
$ cat sample.txt > /dev/null
```

*In terminal #2:*

```
KiB Mem:   7968336 total,  7011896 used,   956440 free,   267336 buffers
```

*Notice the output of `fatrace` in terminal #3:*

```
cat(25940): R /home/saml/tst/162600/sample.txt
cat(25940): R /home/saml/tst/162600/sample.txt
cat(25940): RC /home/saml/tst/162600/sample.txt
```

*Now remove the file from RAM, in terminal #4:*

```
$ sudo dd of=/home/saml/tst/162600/sample.txt \
    oflag=nocache conv=notrunc,fdatasync count=0
```

*Note the output of `fatrace` in terminal #2:*

```
dd(26229): O /home/saml/tst/162600/sample.txt
dd(26229): CW /home/saml/tst/162600/sample.txt
```

*Note the RAM in terminal #3:*

```
KiB Mem:   7968336 total,  6908364 used,  1059972 free,   267364 buffers
```

So it would seem that all of the that was consumed by the file in RAM is freed.

### Potential Method #3 - python-fadvise

Thanks to a comment by @frostchutz, there's another tool, a Python script, named `[pyadvise][4]` which provides a much simpler interface than the above `dd` methods. This script makes use of the same `posix_fadvise(2)` interface.

*Example*

```
$ sudo pyadvise --help
Usage: 
    pyadvise [options] [FILE]..

Options:
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit
  -w, --willneed    The specified files will be accessed in the near future
  -s, --sequential  The application expects to access the specified files
                    sequentially (with lower offsets read before higher ones)
  -d, --dontneed    The specified files will not be accessed in the near
                    future
  -r, --random      The specified files will be accessed in random order
  -o, --noreuse     The specified files will be accessed only once. Under
                    Linux, this operation is a no-op; see contrib/copyfileobj-
                    fadvise.py in the python-fadvise source tree for an
                    example on how to achieve approximately the same effect
  -n, --normal      Indicates that the application has no advice to give about
                    its access pattern for the specified files. If no advice
                    is given for an open file, this is the default assumption
  -v, --verbose     Explain what is being done
```

And if we repeat the above test and use `pyadvise` in place of `dd`:

```
$ pyadvise -d /home/saml/tst/162600/sample.txt
```

I noticed an identical drop in the RAM being consumed as before when I used `dd`.

Comment: `dd` works for me. I ended up with https://chris-lamb.co.uk/projects/python-fadvise myself which is the same thing in a more obvious command.

Comment: @frostschutz - very cool. I hadn't heard of this until Gilles asked if anyone knew how to do this in chat. `python-fadvise` is much easier, I've added an example showing `dd`.

Comment: The link for the python script should be moved into the main body of the question. Comments can disappear without trace. A edit will at worst still remain in history. Having said, that, a Google search finds it easily, so not a big deal.

Comment: It even seems to work without sudo, so anyone who can see a file (even without write permission) can have its cache dropped, that's... interesting.

Comment: @frostschutz - I already moved it when it was posted. I've also dropped the `sudo`.

Comment: @slm dd does not work for ntfs-3g partition, any suggestion?

Comment: @Wang - these are the options available. If you have a new question or a follow-up to this question, always ask a new question, comments aren't really the place to do this. Reference this question + answer in your new question.

Comment: There is [`os.posix_fadvise()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.posix_fadvise) in Python's standard libray now.

Comment: None of these methods seem to work for me. I compared the effect of `echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` to the first 2 `dd` commands, and the python `fadvise` call. Only `drop_caches` changed the speed of reading the file.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding @geekosaur's answer you can force the use of `O_DIRECT` by using LD_PRELOAD and the program here: http://arighi.blogspot.com/2007/04/how-to-bypass-buffer-cache-in-linux.html

That code forces `O_DIRECT` for all files. However, simply adding some more strncmp logic in `__do_wrap_open` you can selectively apply O_DIRECT.

Disclaimer: I have not tested this.

Answer (score 3):

You can open individual files with the `O_DIRECT` flag (see `man 2 open`) — read the **NOTES** section of that manpage carefully, and consider whether you also want/need `O_SYNC`.

Comment: Well, my process is `cat`, and I'd rather not rewrite it.  :)  I was hoping for a command-line tool or a `/proc/sys` knob.

Comment: Worse than that, I suspect you really mean you're using redirection, so your process is the shell.  I don't know of a per-file way to control this aside from the `open` flag; you would indeed need to write a program to do it.  (`cat -u` only disables `stdio` buffering, not OS buffering.)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to prevent a file from being cached is to use O_DIRECT. dd is your friend.
If you don't want to use O_DIRECT, notice that the damage might be done already afterwards (other more important things might be discarded from the cache).

```
# fgrep MemFree: /proc/meminfo
4691788 KB
# dd if=massivefile of=/dev/null bs=2M  
# fadv <massivefile
# fgrep MemFree: /proc/meminfo
5097264 KB
```

where fadv.c is (use stdin to make the code ultra simple):

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ posix_fadvise(0, 0, lseek(0, 0, SEEK_END), POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED);
  return 0;
}
```

Notice that afterwards there is more free memory than before, meaning data that was in the cache before was thrown out.
However if you read the file with O_DIRECT:

```
  # fgrep MemFree: /proc/meminfo
  MemFree:         5091464 kB
  # dd if=verylargefile bs=2M of=/dev/null iflag=direct
  6141+1 records in
  6141+1 records out
  12880669515 bytes (13 GB) copied, 72,7641 s, 177 MB/s
  # fgrep MemFree: /proc/meminfo
  MemFree:         5074164 kB
```

Now there's a little less memory free, meaning other activity used up some memory, but the actual read of this 13GB file didn't wash the cache.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to force a file to always use O_SYNC you can mark it as so in the extended attributes with `chattr +S $file`:

man chattr:

> When a file with the 'S' attribute set is modified,  the  changes  are
>   written synchronously  on  the  disk;  this  is  equivalent  to the
>   'sync' mount option applied to a subset of the files.

O_SYNC forces the data+metadata to be written to the disk buffers, but it still passes through the page cache. O_DIRECT bypasses the page cache.

But be aware that opening it with O_DIRECT would be detrimental to performance, if the big file it's just being appended the difference might be small. But if the big file it's been rewritten at random places O_DIRECT will be a very big hit on performance, even taking into account that it having it in cache could possibly evict from cache some of the small read files.

If you have the ram to keep all the small files there, you could approach the problem the other way. Make sure that the small files are always in ram, then I would suggest to copy them to [tmpfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt):

> tmpfs puts everything into the kernel internal caches and grows and
>   shrinks to accommodate the files it contains

Comment: `chattr +S` is not the same thing as `O_DIRECT`, it's the same thing as `O_SYNC`. `O_DIRECT` causes **reads** not to be cached (which is what this question is about), and writes not to be buffered, with no guarantee. `O_SYNC` causes only **writes** not to be buffered.

Comment: @Gilles you are right, I read the question and thought about flushing data to the disk as I had done it before. And there is another subtle, but important in this case, difference between O_DIRECT and O_SYNC, O_DIRECT bypasses the page cache, but O_SYNC not, it forces the data (and metadata) to be flushed to the disk, but it passes through page cache and is kept there to speedup reads. Should I change O_DIRECT for O_SYNC in my answer as not to let it stay with a wrong affirmation?

Comment: This question asks about keeping a big file that it's been written out of the cache. I think opening it with O_DIRECT would be detrimental to performance, and if the big file it's just being appended the difference might be small. But if the big file it's been rewritten at random places O_DIRECT will be a very big hit on performance, even taking into account that it could possibly evict from cache some of the small read files.

Comment: Changing `O_DIRECT` to `O_SYNC` would make your answer internally consistent, but still wrong considering the question.

Comment: O_SYNC only forces write through, but make no difference for reads and will make zero difference on the cache, as the data that was read/written will stay.