# Unclear htop output when measuring IO usage of a dummy process

Tags: io, htop

I write a simple `test.sh` script which only does this: `while true; do cp ./target-file ./target-file.tmp; done` wherein `target-file` is created using `dd if=/dev/urandom of=target-file bs=1M count=100` and has `du -h target-file` output of `101M target-file`.

I attempt to measure disk IO of this process using htop. I enabled all of these columns (availabe in htop: <kbd>F2</kbd> -> select "Columns" -> on the right scroll to the bottom):

[image: htop columns]

This is sample output at some time (see bottom row):

[image: htop grab of running process]

I am clear on few parameters: `RD_CHAR` is greater than `WR_CHAR` and `RD_SYSC` is greater than `WR_SYSC`. Logically, for `cp` to work, it has to first read the file and then write it. So this makes sense.

However, `DISK_READ` is consistently `0.00 B/s`, and `IO_RBYTES` is much much less than `IO_WBYTES`. Obviously, assuming this to mean that the process is reading no bytes per second woud be incorrect. Or to assume that it is writing more information than it has read is incorect too.

**Question**: how to logically understand these very low reported values of `IO_RBYTES` and `DISK_READ`?

Comment: Since you're copying the same file over and over, disk caching might be coming into play. So the file gets read once, is cached, and then written over and over a bunch of times. You can try using a single large file instead, and see if the measurements align with what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the note @Haxiel I knew the different caches in a process but didn't know about file system caching. I tried with a 1GiB file, this time the `DISK_READ` rate still almost always remains 0 (or spikes upto very low values compared to the corresponding write rates. The IO_RBYTES does increase a lot many times but it is still mostly zero and lesser than IO_WBYTES.

Answer (score 3):

Those fields come from `/proc/$pid/io` which you can find documented here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

> rchar: characters read
> The number of bytes which this task has caused to
> be read from storage.  This is simply the sum of
> bytes which this process passed to read(2) and
> similar system calls.  It includes things such as
> terminal I/O and is unaffected by whether or not
> actual physical disk I/O was required (the read
> might have been satisfied from pagecache).
>
> wchar: characters written
> The number of bytes which this task has caused, or
> shall cause to be written to disk.  Similar caveats
> apply here as with rchar.
>
> read_bytes: bytes read
> Attempt to count the number of bytes which this
> process really did cause to be fetched from the
> storage layer.  This is accurate for block-backed
> filesystems.
>
> write_bytes: bytes written
> Attempt to count the number of bytes which this
> process caused to be sent to the storage layer.

There are a few critical subtleties in these definitions.

> I am clear on few parameters: RD_CHAR is greater than WR_CHAR and RD_SYSC is greater than WR_SYSC. Logically, for cp to work, it has to first read the file and then write it. So this makes sense.

Yes, that is correct, however there's more to it. The `rchar` and `wchar` metrics include all reads and writes, including STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR, network, etc...
Now you're just using `cp` and `dd`, which don't output that much, so in this specific scenario, it shouldn't make much difference. But it is something to be aware of when working with more complex processes.

> However, DISK_READ is consistently 0.00 B/s, and IO_RBYTES is much much less than IO_WBYTES. Obviously, assuming this to mean that the process is reading no bytes per second woud be incorrect.

The critical bit to understanding this behavior is:

> read_bytes: bytes read
> Attempt to count the number of bytes which this
> process really did cause to be fetched from the
> storage layer.

In your case, the input data is likely still in the page cache, so you're not actually hitting the disk, you're reading from memory. But since you're writing to a new file, the output is hitting the disk.

Tl;Dr: The *char metrics include **all I/O to/from the process**, including disk, TTY, network, etc. The *bytes metrics are only **physical disk I/O**.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to drop this file from the fs cache on every iteration of the loop? One way I can think of is doing the same operation on 10 random files in cyclic order. But I do not how much caching it will alleviate. Another way I just found is [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36907/drop-a-specific-file-from-the-linux-filesystem-cache). Do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: It's easy to drop the whole page cache, but not so much dropping individual files. The linked answer is probably worth trying. The 10 random files thing sounds unreliable.