# Linux gaslighting me by pretending to write to USB

Tags: usb-drive, cache, block-device

When I boot my Linux and start writing to a USB-backed block device, everything goes fine for the first few times.

Afterwards, if I write to it once more, `dd` reports absurdly huge transfer rates (2.9 GB/s, which isn't possible), and it is seemingly successful. But when I plug it into any other computer, I can clearly see it holds the old data. Yet, my Linux *reports the new data even when plugged back in* (checked with `xxd`)! This should mean that it's holding the data in the cache and not ever flushing it. Only when rebooting does it finally work again.

I've tried many different things: running `sync`, passing `conv=sync`, `conv=fdatasync`, `oflag=direct`, writing 3 to `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, turning off the USB nicely with `udisksctl`, waiting 30 seconds, trying to write zeroes with `cat`, etc. but none of them end up doing anything.

I even switched my Linux system to something else (something I almost never do) because the previous one was a buggy mess anyways, but, unsurprisingly, Linux is the buggy mess. This is a brand new, 1-day old Debian 11.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show us exact command use ? (*start writing to a USB-backed block device* is ambiguous) did you use `cp` to write file to a file system ? was it unmount ? if you use `dd` which device did you use ? (I suspect you use something like `dd of=/dev/usba` this would write to a **file** name `/dev/usba`)

Comment: What I used was `dd if=drive.bin of=/dev/sda bs=1M status=progress`, and it worked fine until it suddenly didn't

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent dd's progress from being meaningless on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379947/how-to-prevent-dds-progress-from-being-meaningless-on-linux)

Comment: You have to run `eject /dev/sdX` before removing any usb storage device (or use whatever similar button in your GUI). Not only Linux is caching and lying, but the usb's device firmware does it too. I'm quite skeptical of *some* of the your claims, though.

Comment: The simplest explanation is you had written to `/dev/sda` before it was created as a block device file, so your USB got `sdb`. Or maybe it was already `sdb` for whatever reason. Or maybe this time it was not detected at the hardware level (one of my old laptops sometimes does not detect a USB drive until plugged in again). Anyway `sda` was a regular file with no connection to the USB whatsoever. You did not notice and worked with the regular file until the reboot. `/dev` is a virtual filesystem (in memory), the reboot destroyed the file and allowed the things to work as you expect.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I doubt this is so, because I always check `lsblk` before any writing; the USB is always in `/dev/sda`

Comment: @UncleBilly So far, it works consistently. But it worked without `eject` the first few times, could you explain why? Feel free to write as an answer, and I'll mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `eject` before unplugging seems to neutralize the problem.