# Why is my very old USB2 Harddisk faster than expected?

Tags: performance, write

http://web1.heissa.de/usb2_speed.pdf

From the spec, I would expect a max. write rate of `60 Mbyte/s`.

But today a simple test told me it‘s `226 MB/s`. Is it possible that this is a trick of kernel 4,18 and the real write flush follows later and my test is not valid?

Specification:

```
USB 2.0 ,480 Mbit/s (60 MByte/s)
USB 3.0 ,5 Gbit/s (625 MByte/s)
```

So my first test was to check the usb2 speed of my Dell Inc. Latitude E6420, BIOS A23 01/04/2016 and indeed it‘s `480 Mbit/s`.

```
cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/speed
480
```

Comment: Disable write cache, write directly onto disk then test again.

Comment: Very good, thanks a lot that works:hdparm -W0 /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 setting drive write-caching to 0 (off)
 write-caching =  0 (off)
root@oc:~# time dd if=/dev/urandom of=/srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-FUJITSU_MJA2320BH_G2_K92MT9C29J5D-part2/rand1.txt bs=1G count=30
dd: warning: partial read (33554431 bytes); suggest iflag=fullblock
0+30 records in
0+30 records out
1006632930 bytes (1.0 GB, 960 MiB) copied, 112.356 s, 9.0 MB/s

real 1m52.466s

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336627/when-is-there-a-need-to-flush-caches-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

solved!

hdparm -W0 /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 setting drive write-caching to 0 (off)
 write-caching =  0 (off)

time dd if=/dev/urandom of=/srv/dev-disk-by-id-ata-FUJITSU_MJA2320BH_G2_K92MT9C29J5D-part2/rand1.txt bs=1G count=30
dd: warning: partial read (33554431 bytes); suggest iflag=fullblock
0+30 records in
0+30 records out
1006632930 bytes (1.0 GB, 960 MiB) copied, 112.356 s, 9.0 MB/s

real    1m52.466s

Comment: explains why this is only needed in case of benchmarking; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336627/when-is-there-a-need-to-flush-caches-in-linux